# Ng-grid editable grid does not get focus on click

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I need a grid that the user can edit. I also need to be able to add an extra row to the data set, preferably from the grid. But first of all i need to be able to edit the data.

I thought i could just use plain 2 way binding for this. But clicking on a cell does not make it editable. I have added enableCellEdit:true and also tried to add enableCellEditOnFocus.
I would prefer just having all the cells editable without having to use a template.
The cells contain a number and a date.

Below are my grid options that i pass the grid.

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'account.interests',enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'rate',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      width: 60
    },
    {
      field: 'date',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      cellFilter: 'date:\'yyyy-MM-dd\''
    }]
  };
```

And my grid in the view:

```
<div ng-if="showInterestRates" >
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the edit future you must add the [edit module](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable): 'ui.grid.edit' module and you must include the ui-grid-edit directive on your grid element.

Comment: for `cellEditOnFocus` you also must add the module cellNav. At least it is so in the version 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both `ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav` in your div

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
```

and in your module

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit','ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.select'])
```